# How to print all text in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm building a simple parser with beautifulsoup4. After getting all values I need I'm trying to print them, but getting only one value, not all of them.
Website I'm parsing: [Click](https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes)

And here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = requests.get('https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes', headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
html = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')

a = html.select('div > div' '[class = "name"]')
print(a[0].text)
```

Comment: standard rule: if you get `list` then you need `for`-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over result of `.select()` (note: CSS selector `[class="name"]` can be written as `.name`):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = requests.get(
    "https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes", headers={"User-agent": "your bot 0.1"}
)
soup = BS(response.content, "html.parser")

for name in soup.select(".name"):
    print(name.text)
```

Prints:

```
Abaddon
Alchemist
Ancient Apparition
Anti-Mage

...

Witch Doctor
Wraith King
Zeus
```

---

If you want the result in list form:

```py
out = [name.text for name in soup.select(".name")]
print(out)
```